# bada 1 and JSON

Tags: json, bada

Bada 2.0 has classes to handle JSON.

Bada 1 doesn't have these classes.

How to work with JSON in bada? I have tried jsoncpp(http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/), but it does not work (iostream: No such file or directory)

The same problem with JsonBox (https://bitbucket.org/madbranch/jsonbox/)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

I used this project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cajun-jsonapi/ with some modifications, described here:http://ask.badadev.com/questions/2957/json-parser-for-bada

> - replace "null" -> with "null_" because of Bada headers brain-damaging #define
> - use istream/ostream instead of iostream
> - comment out iomanip and std::setprecision() in writer.inl

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I worked with the platform, but as I recall Bada uses (or used; I haven't developed under Bada 2) a subset of modern C++, hence the provision of Bada-custom classes for things like strings, arrays, etc. That's why you may have difficulty with some off-the-shelf C++ code.

As an alternative, you can use a C JSON library. It's slightly more awkward to walk the data after it's been parsed (because C has no inherent concept of a `map`, for example) but I've otherwise had good experiences with [cJSON](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjson/) and [json.org](http://json.org) lists a bunch of other options.